# Integral with Sin(x)

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

[image]

I got the integral as -5 cos (x), tried to plug the the top and bottom limits in, but can't seem to get the right answer. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're using degrees for your cosine. You ought to use radians.

Answer (score 1):

We have $$[-5\cos x]_{\pi/4}^{{5\pi}/2}=-5\left[\cos\dfrac\pi4-\cos\dfrac{5\pi}2\right]=-5\left[\frac1{\sqrt2}-0\right]$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you used the degree setting instead of radians

Answer (score 0):

You're right that $$\int_{\pi/4}^{5\pi/2} 5\sin x\; \textrm{d}x = \left[-5\cos x\right]_{\pi/4}^{5\pi/2}$$

There's obviously a mistake in you evaluating $5\cos (5\pi/2)$ and $5\cos (\pi/4)$. What do you think they should be? Hint: they are 'special' angles in the sense that there is a nice expression for them...